# Params Values not picked up in input message Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The parameter value from choice is not being picked up in the input message rather it is writing plain text in the input message, the bolded should have the params value from choice parameter:

You have selcted the standby node **${VAR_STANDBY_node}** and standby dbase **${VAR_STANDBY_dbase}** .Do you want to proceed?

script :

```
stage('check_count_standby') {

    node("$primary_node") {
        unstash 'db-switchover'

script {
VAR_STANDBY = sh (script: 'sudo cat /pathtofile/count_standby.txt', returnStdout: true).trim()
VAR_STANDBY_node = sh (script: "echo ${params.standby_node}", returnStdout: true).trim()
VAR_STANDBY_dbase = sh (script: "echo ${params.standby_dbase}", returnStdout: true).trim()
if(VAR_STANDBY > "1") {
     input message: 'You have selcted the standby node ${VAR_STANDBY_node} and standby dbase ${VAR_STANDBY_dbase} .Do you want to proceed?'
}



}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved now: I supposed to use double quotes in the input message: ""

```
stage('check_count_standby') {

    node("$primary_node") {
        unstash 'db-switchover'

script {
VAR_STANDBY = sh (script: 'sudo cat /pathtofile/count_standby.txt', returnStdout: true).trim()
VAR_STANDBY_node = sh (script: "echo ${params.standby_node}", returnStdout: true).trim()
VAR_STANDBY_dbase = sh (script: "echo ${params.standby_dbase}", returnStdout: true).trim()
if(VAR_STANDBY > "1") {
     input message: "You have selcted the standby node ${VAR_STANDBY_node} and standby dbase ${VAR_STANDBY_dbase} .Do you want to proceed?"
}



}

}
}
```